# Time series error Unsupported type passed to argument 'data'

Tags: r

I have this data (time is a character variable):

```
problem = data.frame(time = c("2010-01", "2010-02", "2010-03", "2010-04", "2010-05", "2010-06", "2010-07", "2010-08", "2010-09", "2010-10", "2010-11", "2010-12"),
                     var = c(15, 16, 16, 14, 17, 12, 11, 15, 16, 18, 14, 11))


library(forecast)

fit <- auto.arima(problem$var)

pred <- forecast(fit, h=12, level=0.95)
```

I try to make time series graphs:

```
library(dygraphs)

dygraph(cbind(problem, pred$lower, pred$mean, pred$upper), main = "title") %>%
    dySeries("problem$var", label = "Actual") %>%
    dySeries(c("pred$lower", "pred$mean", "pred$upper"), label = "Predicted", fill = "red")
```

I get error: `Unsupported type passed to argument 'data'.`

How I can fix?

Comment: You need a timeseries data and not a dataframe

Comment: thx! can u please explain what you mean?

Comment: The first argument of [`dygraph`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dygraphs/versions/1.1.1.6/topics/dygraph) should be a time series object

Comment: like this? ts(problem$var, start=c(2010,1), frequency=12)

Comment: maybe you can show me later please how i can get it to run correct? thx!